# Mejorar menú de esta aplicación

Tags: powershell

He hecho un programa en PowerShell en modo consola, en el cual tienes que pulsar botones idnicados para abrir y cerrar la bandeja del lector de discos.

```html
╔====================================╗
║            PowerShell              ║
╠====================================╣
║     Control bandeja del lector     ║
╠====================================╣
║                                    ║
║    A) Abrir.                       ║
║    C) Cerrar.                      ║
║    I) Información.                 ║
║    S) Presiona 'S' para salir.     ║
║                                    ║
╚====================================╝
      Elegir una Opción:
```

Cuando pulse A, abre la bandeja. No lo hace directamente, luego tengo que pulsar Enter para ir atrás al menú.

¿Hay alguna manera de pulsar el botón abrir o cerar sin tener que pulsar Enter?

El mensaje de abrir y cerrar tiene que aparecer.

**Código fuente PowerShell:**

```html
$MemDef = @"
[DllImport("winmm.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
   public static extern int mciSendStringA(
   string lpstrCommand,
   string lpstrReturnString,
   int uReturnLength,
   IntPtr hwndCallback);
"@

$winnm = Add-Type -memberDefinition $MemDef -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue' -passthru -name mciSendString
function Set-CDAudioDoor {
 Param(
  [ValidateSet("open", "closed")][String[]]$Mode = 'open'
 )
 $winnm::mciSendStringA("set cdaudio door $mode", $null, 0,0)}

function mostrarMenu
{ 
     param ([string]$Titulo = ' Control bandeja del lector ', 
     [string]$PS = ' PowerShell              ') 
     cls 
     Write-Host "╔====================================╗"
     Write-Host "║           $PS║"
     Write-Host "╠====================================╣"
     Write-Host "║    $Titulo    ║"
     Write-Host "╠====================================╣" 
     Write-Host "║                                    ║"
     Write-Host "║    A) Abrir.                       ║"
     Write-Host "║    C) Cerrar.                      ║" 
     Write-Host "║    I) Información.                 ║" 
     Write-Host "║    S) Presiona 'S' para salir.     ║" 
     Write-Host "║                                    ║"
     Write-Host "╚====================================╝"
}

do 
{ 
     mostrarMenu 
     $input = Read-Host "      Elegir una Opción"
     switch ($input) 
     { 
           'a' { 
                cls 
                'Abriendo...'
                Set-CDAudioDoor open
                'Abierto.'
                ' '
           } 'c' { 
                cls 
                'Cerrando...' 
                Set-CDAudioDoor closed
                'Cerrado.'
           } 'i' { 
                cls 
                'PowerShell'
                '=========='
                Get-Host
                'Electrónica PIC'
                '==============='
                ''
                'e-mail: metaconta@gmail.com'
                ''
           } 's' { 
                return 
           }  
     } 
     pause 
} 
until ($input -eq 's')
```

Tiene que ser como este de abajo, pero no se adaptarlo a PowerShell. Abajo es C#.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace Bandeja_consola_cs
{
    class Program
    {
        // Importar dll.
        [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
        public static extern Int32 mciSendString(string lpstrCommand, StringBuilder lpstrReturnString,
        int uReturnLength, IntPtr hwndCallback);

        public static StringBuilder rt = new StringBuilder(127);

        // Eventos.
        public static void DoEventsAbriendo()
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 6);
            Console.Write("Abriendo...");
        }

        public static void DoEventsCerrando()
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 6);
            Console.Write("Cerrando...");
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Título de la ventana.
            Console.Title = "Consola C# 2017";

            // Tamaño ventana consola.
            Console.WindowWidth = 29; // X. Ancho.
            Console.WindowHeight = 8; // Y. Alto. 

            // Cursor invisible.
            Console.CursorVisible = false;

            // Posición del mansaje en la ventana.
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
            Console.Write(@"Control bandeja del lector:

A - Abrir bandeja.
C - Cerrar bandeja.
===========================");

            ConsoleKey key;
            //Console.CursorVisible = false;
            do
            {
                key = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;

                string mensaje = string.Empty;

                // Leer tecla selecconada por el usuario.
                switch (key)
                {
                    case ConsoleKey.A:
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 6);
                        DoEventsAbriendo();
                        // Abre la bandeja.
                        mciSendString("set CDAudio door open", rt, 127, IntPtr.Zero);
                        mensaje = "Abierto.";
                        break;

                    case ConsoleKey.C:
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 6);
                        DoEventsCerrando();
                        // Cierra la bandeja.
                        mciSendString("set CDAudio door closed", rt, 127, IntPtr.Zero);
                        mensaje = "Cerrado.";
                        break;
                }

                // Posición de los mensajes.
                Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 6);
                Console.Write("           ");
                Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 6);
                Console.Write(mensaje);

            }
            // Salir de la plicación al pulsar la tecla Escape.
            while (key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
        }
    }
}
```

Saludos.

Comment: PowerShell no es un lenguaje de programación, mas importante aún, en que lenguaje lo desarrollaste: C#, bat...? Tambien recuerda añadir el código del programa.

Comment: Edité arriba y añadí el código fuente que me olvidé de PowerShell.
Dejo el código C# del como debería de ser.

Answer (score 0):

Debes reemplazar la siguiente línea:

```
$input = Read-Host "      Elegir una Opción"
```

Con lo siguiente:

```
$input = ($host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyUp')).character
```

Y también remover la línea que dice "pause" y agregar al final del formato del menú lo siguiente:

```
Write-host "      Elegir una Opción:"
```

El código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
$MemDef = @"
[DllImport("winmm.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern int mciSendStringA(
    string lpstrCommand,
    string lpstrReturnString,
    int uReturnLength,
    IntPtr hwndCallback);
"@

$winnm = Add-Type -memberDefinition $MemDef -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue' -passthru -name mciSendString
function Set-CDAudioDoor {
    Param(
    [ValidateSet("open", "closed")][String[]]$Mode = 'open'
    )
    $winnm::mciSendStringA("set cdaudio door $mode", $null, 0,0)}

function mostrarMenu
{ 
        param ([string]$Titulo = ' Control bandeja del lector ', 
        [string]$PS = ' PowerShell              ') 
        cls 
        Write-Host "╔====================================╗"
        Write-Host "║           $PS║"
        Write-Host "╠====================================╣"
        Write-Host "║    $Titulo    ║"
        Write-Host "╠====================================╣" 
        Write-Host "║                                    ║"
        Write-Host "║    A) Abrir.                       ║"
        Write-Host "║    C) Cerrar.                      ║" 
        Write-Host "║    I) Información.                 ║" 
        Write-Host "║    S) Presiona 'S' para salir.     ║" 
        Write-Host "║                                    ║"
        Write-Host "╚====================================╝"
        Write-host "      Elegir una Opción:"
}

do 
{ 
        mostrarMenu 
        $input = ($host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyUp')).character
        switch ($input) 
        { 
            'a' { 
                cls 
                'Abriendo...'
                Set-CDAudioDoor open
                'Abierto.'
                ' '
                pause
            } 'c' { 
                cls 
                'Cerrando...' 
                Set-CDAudioDoor closed
                'Cerrado.'
                pause
            } 'i' { 
                cls 
                'PowerShell'
                '=========='
                Get-Host
                'Electrónica PIC'
                '==============='
                ''
                'e-mail: metaconta@gmail.com'
                ''
                pause
            } 's' { 
                return 
            }  
        }
} 
until ($input -eq 's')
```

Comment: Al ejecutarlo, parpadea mucho la pantalla. Es como si se pusiera muchas veces el menú y luego se borra para luego dibujarse. Los pulsadores no sirven.

Comment: Lo revisé de nuevo y me funciona correctamente en mi equipo. Te adjunto un captura de como lo veo yo: https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21AKUjU95vOhmQMiM&cid=C218AF731A3060A5&id=C218AF731A3060A5%2173381&parId=C218AF731A3060A5%21125&o=OneUp

Comment: Lo hice con ISE qque da problemas. Lo hice llamando PowerShell, no da problemas. Vaya con el ISE. Por cierto. La idea, que los mensajes de abriendo y cerrando, tiene que estar en el propio menú. ¿Cómo haces esas capturas con gif para mostrarte ejemplo con C#? Es muy útil ayudarse así. ;)

Comment: La herramienta es ScreenToGif: http://www.screentogif.com/downloads

Comment: Buenas:
Te paso la animación de C#. Desde que pulse un botón, muestra el mensaje en el menú principal como indica aquí.
https://www.subeimagenes.com/img/visual-1874400.gif
Lo que no se si en PowerShell tiene capacidad para poner los textos en cualquier parte de la pantalla como si lo ahce enla consola de C#.